# Content Management via WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: cms

Can I create a Sharepoint 2013 (enterprise) website where permissioned users can content manage HTML pages via a WYSIWYG editor?

Answer (score 0):

On SP2013 or earlier you would have to write your own editor (plenty of libraries around)

On SharePoint Online you can use the (new) built OneDrive editor.

It will not open .HTML files by default due to (historic) mimetype issues and thus asks you to download the HTML file.

BUT, if you can construct the correct URI you can open any file in that editor

- Open your Library with the Modern Experience Library view
- Upload a .txt file
- Open the .txt file
- [editor should open in a new Tab]
- Analyse the URL and work your (existing) HTML filename in there